# Proof of a six digit number

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

How can we prove that the number $142857$ is the only six digit number with the property that if I put the last digit before the first digit we get $5$ times our number so:

$$\frac{714285}{142857}=5$$

So my question is:

Proof that $142857$ is the only six digit number for which I can put it's last digit before the first digit and get a number that is an integer times my chosen number (5 in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the first digit and $b$ be the remaining digits.

$$100000a+b=50b+5a\implies49b=99995a\implies 7b=14285a$$

Knowing $a<10, a=7$ is the only solution.

If you do not restrict the ratio to $5$ the n there are other solutions as well, for example since ${99996\over39}=2564$ we can have many choices of $a,b$ such as $820512=4\cdot205128$

Comment: Defining a and b would be helpful,,,